# Create Long length Haptic in iWatch swift

Tags: swift4, swift5, watchos, haptic-feedback, watchos-5

Hi i am aware that apple does not allow us to create core haptic in iWatch instead it make us to use the default haptic it has. But the default haptics are of short length. Can I get help to know how to create long length haptic. Like it should last for 4 seconds.